# NullPointerException org.hibernate.cfg.OneToOneSecondPass.doSecondPass

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am using Hibernate 3.0

I have the following tables and corresponding entries,

```
Table A:
Integer aid;
Integer bid;

Table B:
Integer bid;

@Entity
@Table(name="A")
public class A {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="aid")
Integer AId;
@OneToOne(targetEntity=B.class)
@JoinColumn(name="bid", referencedColumnName="bid")
B b;
}


@Entity
@Table(name="B")
public class B {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="bid")
Integer bId;

@OneToOne(targetEntity=A.class, mappedBy="b")
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="bid")
A a;
}
```

When I try to run my spring application with the above configuration, I get the following error,

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.cfg.OneToOneSecondPass.doSecondPass(OneToOneSecondPass.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1163)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1148)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:720)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
```

I need reference of A in B, even though B is not having any reference for A.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="bid")` from `class B`, it is not needed and maybe it'll fix the error.

**EDIT**

This is a pretty basic setup, so to keep it simple try this code

```
@Entity
@Table(name="A")
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="aid")
    private Integer AId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="bid")
    private B b;

    // getters and setters

}

@Entity
@Table(name="B")
public class B {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="bid")
    private Integer bId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="b")
    private A a;

    // getters and setters

}
```

Comment: removed the annotation, still the same error.
I want the reference of A in B, but B is not having any column for A.

Comment: @GokulKulkarni Yes, that is OK, and with this `@JoinColumn` removed, mapping look good. Don't know what causes the exception...

Comment: I tried the same above configuration, sorry to say, still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The exception your getting is beacuse your trying to define the mapping on both sides. If you want the reference of A in B, you should do

```
@Entity
@Table(name="A")
public class A {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="aid")
Integer AId;

@OneToOne(targetEntity=B.class)
B b;
}


@Entity
@Table(name="B")
public class B {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="bid")
Integer bId;

@OneToOne(targetEntity=A.class, mappedBy="b")
A a;
}
```

Watch out for the bugs in older hibernate versions

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/ANN-554

Comment: The tables are as follows,
Table A:
Integer aid;
Integer bid;

Table B:
Integer bid;

Comment: edited, I understood from your comment that you won't to change that

Comment: I tried this, even then the same error, I am using hibernate 3.0, does that release has any problem?

Comment: very likely https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/ANN-554, the example post is almost the same